# Meaning of this sentence by a yakuza

Tags: translation, meaning, verbs, manga

Context: in [this manga](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%AA%E3%82%AF%E3%83%89%E3%82%A6), an ex boxer now working for a yakuza group has just attended the funeral of his boss (組長). After the funeral, he sits alone and watches his pinkie. Then thinks:

> 何考えてんだ俺は…　あめェよ…　命【たま】かけなきゃならねェ世界【とこ】で生かされてんだ。あめェよ…　**小指じゃ命につりあわねェっての。**

In the manga the word 世界 is often used to refer to the boxing world, and I think in this case too. I understand that he is talking about the yubitsume ritual, but the meaning of the last sentence is not clear to me, the verb in particular. I think it literally means "a pinkie can't match life", but what does he actually mean by that? What is the general meaning of the whole sentence? Also, why 命 has たま as furigana? My attempt:

> What the hell am I thinking? I'm so naive... I am forced to live in a world where you have to risk your life. I'm so naive... a pinkie can't be compared to life.

Unfortunately, the manga doesn't provide much context because it focuses on the boxing part, this is just a minor scene. I don't know why he thinks about cutting his finger, maybe he feels guilty about the death of his boss?

Thank you for your help!

EDIT: maybe my explanation wasn't clear, but in the end he doesn't cut his finger. [Here you can see](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1SWKm89rpifyLFgGo9DtxGW8jMltShVMO) the page in question (page 29) and some pages before it. In the first page, you can see an unknown member of the yakuza clan with his amputated pinkie. This is all the context the manga provides, after these pages it goes back to the main story.

Comment: Is ex-boxer a trainer now?

Comment: @kimiTanaka No, he isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I think this 世界 is used to refer to Yakuza world because the ex-boxer who said that is now working for a Yakuza group.

Dictionaries say that 釣り合う means "match、coordinate、balance and equal". I think 小指じゃ命につりあわない means "The value of a pinkie isn't equal with a life.", that is to say, "A life is worth more than a pinkie". This "The value of a pinkie" means "the action of cutting a pinkie" because yubitsume ritual is worth for Yakuza.

In addition, 命 is called たま in yakuza world. You can hear it in yakuza movies.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I not sure about what 世界 refers to because I don't understand the tense of 生かされてんだ. Is it past or present? I think that if it is past, it refers to the boxing world, if it is present it refers to the yakuza world.

Comment: @Marco It is present. 生かされていたんだ is past.

Comment: Thank you. And what do you think is the general meaning of the whole sentence?

Comment: We need to know this situation. Why did he cut his pinkie? Why did his boss die?

Comment: Sorry, maybe my explanation wasn't clear, but in the end he doesn't cut his finger. The reason why his boss died is unknown. I updated the question providing more context.

Comment: 原文を読むと、命（いのち）ではなく（たま）らしいですね。魂の方。

Comment: Well, I can't say more than my answer only by the context. Yubitsume ritual is performed to ask for permission  when yakuza had a mistake or they quit yakuza world.

Comment: @kimiTanaka ありがとう。I corrected the question accordingly.

Comment: @YuuichiTam Thank you anyway! If no other answer is provided, I will accept yours.

Comment: @YuuichiTam One last question: what is the meaning of 生かされている? "To be forced to live"? Or "to be exploited"?

Comment: 生かされている seems to have some translations. For example, to be made to live, to be allowed to live, to be meant to live, etc.

Comment: @YuuichiTam Do you think in this case it expresses obligation or permission?

Comment: I am not sure because I don't know why he became yakuza. If he wanted to be yakuza, it would be close to permission, but If he didn't want to be, it would be close to obligation.